# Elevated 200 sq ft addition needs skirting

Tags: skirting, addition

I'm a decent laborer, and a contractor and I built a 200 sq ft addition to my home. A deck used to be there and we re-used its foundation. (if that raises eyebrows, we sistered all joists, added concrete posts, replaced all joist hangers, etc etc etc - foundation is rock solid). Contractor is gone and I'm on my own.

One side of the addition is against the brick wall of my home. The other 3 are exposed on the ground. I live in Chicago - so I want to add skirting, for protection from the cold and from animals. The ground along the 3 sides is mostly dirt, but there are 2 small sections where it's sidewalk. No issues tearing that up. The height of what I'd need to install below the addition varies from about 9-13".

So obviously I want to keep cold air and critters out, but I'm concerned about whatever I install rotting, attracting insects, etc.

I've considered a few options, but I'm really not sure what to do.

Main thing I'm thinking: install PT 2x4's as nailers, parallel with the ground. Then nail something in that can have ground contact, perhaps even go under ground a bit for more support. I thought about PT plywood, but even when they say ground contact is ok, I'm concerned about attracting insects that can cause problems/rotting. The plywood would be ideal, though. And I could later install some stone/brick veneer, or at the least paint it. I'm wondering if gravel, or something, instead of dirt, would be better for PT plywood to go into.

I have a bunch of fiber cement siding left over that I considered installing into the nailers vertically, but without a plywood backing it'd be very flimsy. I'm fine with vinyl too, I just want this done and ready for winter.

I also considered using an C, U, something, channel, on the ground, and then from there I could fit in PT plywood and nail it to the 2x4's. I found something, but only on some random website, that looks like a C channel and it's made to be spiked in to the ground. This would avoid that (potential) issue of putting PT plywood into the ground.

I also imagine some venting is necessary. If vinyl is a viable option, I'd just get something vented. If I went with plywood, if necessary, I'd probably install a small fascia-style vent on a couple sides. Any help would be very much appreciated!  Thank you for reading.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Title has the intent but there is no question being asked. One could easily infer multiple questions such as which product to use, how to build it, is venting necessary, all kinds of things. OP needs to clarify what exactly the question is, anything other than that is just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a little more time consuming than you want right now but perhaps you could form out a small perimeter on the 3 sides and pour a small strip of concrete to give you something real and lasting to fasten to.  Also, I've often thought about using a composite decking material for this type of project.  Just install them vertically and leave out the gaps.  Also, frame out a couple of vents.  Hope you come up with a solution!

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your response! I think this would work really well! I could secure PT 2x4's to the concrete, add PT 2x4's as nailers, parallel with the ground, and secure PT plywood to both 2x4's. It's just a 200 sq ft room so I think 2 vents should do it. 

I wanted to respond and thank you earlier but I wasn't able to respond until stackexchange support fixed my account. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm glad you found my idea to be a useful one.  I didn't find your situation too difficult to understand either.